# RegisterWaitForSingleObject crash sometime if handle is closed immediately

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm getting a crash sometimes in RegisterWaitForSingleObject (1 out of 10). It seems that although RegisterWaitForSingleObject returns, the internal thread pool is not yet ready.

```
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);

// CRASH IN INTERNAL SOMETIMES
RegisterWaitForSingleObject (&hWaitForChild_,processHandle,OnChildProcessExit, 0,INFINITE,WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);

// If I sleep here, then it seems ok.
//std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (10));
CloseHandle (processHandle);
```

[image]

I can replicate this with a simple sample here. 1 in 10 times, it will crash. How should I be synchronizing it properly without resorting to sleep hack.

https://filedn.com/l3TGy7Y83c247u0RDYa9fkp/temp/stackoverflow/testregister.cpp

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: but you yourself call `CloseHandle (processHandle)` after call `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` - and read msdn - *If this handle is closed while the wait is still pending, the function's behavior is undefined*

Comment: That is STATUS_THREADPOOL_HANDLE_EXCEPTION, exposes how RWFSO is implement under the hood.  You also see the reason why the wait thread bombed, 0xC0000008 == STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE, "An invalid HANDLE was specified".  You see more because a debugger is attached btw, Microsoft is *very* worried about handle recycle attacks and turns a basic error into a hard SEH exception.  And yes, the handle is invalid, you closed it.  Bypassing the threading race with a sleep is of course not correct.  Simple fix, don't call CloseHandle() until your OnChildProcessExit function runs.

Comment: There is a compilable source file there. 

What does it mean by "wait is still pending". If the function have returned with a true/false success value, shouldn't it mean the register is already complete.

Comment: I use OpenProcess to get the handle using process ID, so the handle from OpenProcess is different everytime so meaning I have keep track on which handle is registered at different places.

Comment: *If the function have returned with a true/false success value, shouldn't it mean the register is already complete* - of course no. worked thread begin wait on your handle asynchronous. when `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` - worked thread can yet not begin wait

Comment: and you need understand that handle - this is only index of cell in the some table, where stored pointer to actual object and access.

Comment: *I have keep track on which handle is registered at different places* - special for this and exist *Context* parameter. you need allocate some structure, store here handle on which you register wait with some another data, and close it when callback called

Comment: Are you able to close the handle when the callback is called? I've tried to do this in the callback
    UnregisterWaitEx (handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

It is a race condition as it is blocking call, the documentation says don't call blocking calls,  my testing shows it just stops running the code after that line. If I use NULL instead of INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, it has an overlapped io error. What I have tried (which seems to work) is to defer the UnRegisterWait to a next frame update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on your code spinet:

```
    // THIS CRASHS HERE SOMETIMES

    if (! RegisterWaitForSingleObject (
        &hWaitForChild_

        ,processHandle
        , OnChildProcessExit
        , 0 //this
        , INFINITE
        , WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
    {
        LogDebug ("RegisterWaitForSingleObject failed");
    }

    // If this is enabled, then it won't crash
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (10));

    if (! CloseHandle (processHandle)) // !!!
        LogDebug ("RegisterWaitForSingleObject  Closehandle failed");
```

so you close `processHandle` just after you call `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` for this handle. however if read about [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If this handle is closed while the wait is still pending, the
>   function's behavior is undefined.

if look more deep - try understand - how is `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` worked internally ? it pass `processHandle` to some worker thread. and this thread begin wait for this handle. but this is (pass handle to another thread) is asynchronous operation - say for example internally can be started new thread with this handle as argument, or it can be passed to already existing working thread via some signal. but anyway - worked thread got this handle and begin wait some later. from another side - you just close `processHandle` after `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` return control. so here race - what will be first - or worked thread begin wait on handle (in this case all will be work) or you close this handle. in case you close this handle first - worked thread will be try wait on already invalid handle and raise exception - `STATUS_THREADPOOL_HANDLE_EXCEPTION`.

```
// If this is enabled, then it won't crash
//std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (10));
```

of course - by sleep you give time for worked thread to begin wait on handle. in this case he begin wait before you close handle.

solution - you must not close handle, until `WAITORTIMERCALLBACK Callback` will be not called. you need allocate some context, where place `processHandle` and pass this context to `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. and when you callback will be called - you got pointer to your context back and here and close handle.

also note, that you not need open separate, second, handle for child process, but can use process handle returned by `CreateProcess`

Comment: I can't use the handle by CreateProcess because in the more complex project, I don't call CreateProcess in my process. I have to use OpenProcess.

This is interesting.

`    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`
`       HANDLE h = OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, ProcessID);`


The handles are different everytime unless I Close the handle by OpenProcess. This means the handle is different from CreateProcess and when I use OpenProcess, so that has to be closed differently.

Comment: @Robin - at first you must not use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` access - you need use `SYNCHRONIZE` access only. at second of course every time you will got different handle values

Comment: Can you please explain why? Doesn't PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS include SYNCHRONIZE?

Comment: @Robin - because some processes you simply fail open with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` - you got status access denied error, while with `SYNCHRONIZE` access - if you have debug privilege - you can open any process. always need ask only access which you actually need. if you need only wait on process handle - you need only `SYNCHRONIZE`

Comment: Ok, thanks but this is not the issue right? I will use SYNCHRONIZE but there are times I need to TerminateProcess so I will have to use PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS

Comment: yes, use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` instead `SYNCHRONIZE` not error, but not best solution in all sense.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem like you that an exception occurred while debugging in Visual Studio. I tried many time and finally found the reason. If you close the handle of the process newly created, the program would crash. I tried to close the handles in the callback function, it works perfectly, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    LPTSTR pszCmdLine;
    HANDLE hEvent;
} THREAD_PARAM;

typedef struct {
    TCHAR  szCmdLine[1024];
    HANDLE hWaitObject;
    DWORD  dwProcessId;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD  dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread;
} OBJECT_PARAM;

static void CALLBACK WaitObjectCallback(LPVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    OBJECT_PARAM *pobp = static_cast<OBJECT_PARAM *>(lpParam);

    TCHAR szInfo[1024] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;

    GetExitCodeProcess(pobp->hProcess, &dwExitCode);
    wnsprintf(szInfo, ARRAYSIZE(szInfo), _T("process %u [%s] exit: %u\n"), pobp->dwProcessId, pobp->szCmdLine, dwExitCode);
    OutputDebugString(szInfo);

    //
    // unregister the wait object handle and close the process handle finally
    //
    UnregisterWait(pobp->hWaitObject);
    CloseHandle(pobp->hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pobp->hThread);

    GlobalFree(lpParam);
}

static DWORD CALLBACK ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    THREAD_PARAM *pthp = static_cast<THREAD_PARAM *>(lpParam);

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    BOOL bResult;

    bResult = CreateProcess(nullptr, pthp->pszCmdLine, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi);
    if (bResult)
    {
        OBJECT_PARAM *pobp = static_cast<OBJECT_PARAM *>(GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(OBJECT_PARAM)));

        // make copy of the command line and other informations of the newly created process
        lstrcpyn(pobp->szCmdLine, pthp->pszCmdLine, ARRAYSIZE(pobp->szCmdLine));
        pobp->dwProcessId = pi.dwProcessId;
        pobp->hProcess = pi.hProcess;
        pobp->dwThreadId = pi.dwThreadId;
        pobp->hThread = pi.hThread;

        bResult = RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&pobp->hWaitObject, pi.hProcess, WaitObjectCallback, pobp, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);

        // once it failed...
        if (!bResult)
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }
    }

    // Notify the thread creator that the process is created successfully
    SetEvent(pthp->hEvent);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve it by keeping the handle around until I call  Unregisterwait. It seems to be stable. Thanks to the answers.